# smooth immersion on the circle is periodic

Tags: differential-geometry, periodic-functions

Consider a smooth immersion ($C^\infty$ with nonvanishing first derivative) $f:S^1\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$. Why is such a function necessarily periodic? This was stated in a paper ($1.4$ in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.11290.pdf). To me, for any such function $f$, we have something like
$$f(\cos(x),\sin(x))=f(\cos(x+2\pi),\sin(x+2\pi))$$
so that $f$ is not periodic, but the function $f\circ\varphi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, where $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$ sends $x\mapsto (\cos(x),\sin(x)),$ is periodic. Maybe something like this is meant. But even this only seems to have meaning if we are letting $x$ range over all of $\mathbb{R}$. However, $S^1$ is parametrized just by $S^1=\{e^{ix}\in\mathbb{C}: x\in[0,2\pi)\}$, so the map above would actually just be $f\circ\varphi:[0,2\pi)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, which is not $2\pi$-periodic since $x+2\pi$ is not in the domain of $f\circ\varphi$ for $x\in[0,2\pi)$. It would be like saying $g:[0,2\pi)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ mapping $x\mapsto\cos(x)$ is periodic. So my question is why are smooth immersions on the unit circle necessarily periodic?

Comment: I think the statement is nonsense.

Comment: @TedShifrin I've added the paper. If you have a moment to glance at $1.4$ and comment on his use of the word periodic, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Curves are usually maps from intervals in $\Bbb R$ to the ambient space. Smooth closed curves are periodic maps (with appropriate smoothness conditions) on $\Bbb R$, but we often prefer to think of them as smooth mapson the circle. This is just jumbled terminology.

Comment: @TedShifrin So he's thinking of $C^\infty(S^1,\mathbb{R}^d)$ as smooth periodic functions on $\mathbb{R}$? But how can we capture the periodicity of the function if its domain is just $S^1$?

Comment: There is no such notion. The author messed up.

Comment: Looking at the linked article, it seems that the author just intends to identify functions on $S^1$ with periodic functions on   $\mathbb R$. Where he speaks of periodic curves is certainly just a "slip of the pen".